# Change a file when check in in with GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

is it possible to change a file when check in in new files using GitLab? I tried following ".gitlab-ci.yml"

```
before_script:
  - echo "before_script"
  - ls -l
  - echo "$CI_COMMIT_SHA" >id.txt
  - ls -l


after_script:
  - echo "after_script"
  - ls -l


build-code-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build-code-job"
```

and I see that it changes the id.txt file (size and date). However, this change has no effect on the repository.

The problem is I need a unique ID in one of the files for later use.
Anyone have any idea how I can achieve such an effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "for later use" ? In another job in the same pipeline ? If you can avoid to commit back from the pipeline, do it.

Comment: The database needs to know when a new version is accessing. (Don't ask, I am not responsible for the DB).

I think I found a way, I use got-hooks on the local git.

Comment: if you need to the content of id.txt in another job of your pipeline, your can use [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) keyword to upload it and make it downloadable from another job.

Comment: No, sorry, that is not my intention.
I have to change a file. More precisely a specific line in several files. 

These are files contain sql statements. And with this ID (simply the date+time) a tool sees that there is a new version. And then update the database.

I found a solution with git-hooks. So my problem is solved.